# Trying to fire JQuery from 'onchange' in an Html.DropDownFor helper

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dom

What I am trying to do is set the selected value in dropdown 'b' from dropdown 'a' when the user selects different options from dropdown 'a'.

I'm using the html helper 'DropDownFor' for dropdown 'a' in an MVC project:

```
<%=Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.FrequencyId, frequencyItems, new {  onchange ="ddMonthChange" })%>
```

I want the 'onchange' event to call this JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function ddMonthChange () {
var frequency = document.getElementById("FrequencyId").options[document.getElementById("FrequencyId").selectedIndex].value;
alert("frequency is " + frequency);

});
```

I've a  tag in the same view as dropdown 'a' that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.setMonthly.js"></script>
```

So, clearly this is wrong.  The script does run but only when the view is loaded (the alert pops up) and does nothing when I select a different item from dropdown 'a'.

How do I wire this up so that my script fires when a different item is selected?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change it

```
$(document).on("change","select[name=FrequencyId]",function(){
     alert("frequency is " + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: The right square bracket should be before the quotes ( ]" and not "] ) but it works!  Thanks Gorkhan.

Comment: ah, updated I just wrote from here not used an IDE, and my name is Gökhan not Gorkhan :)

Comment: But how do I set this dropdown <%=Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.PayMonthOne, payMonthItems)%> to another item in payMonthItems in javascript?   I've tried     $(document).on("change", "select[name=FrequencyId]",
        function () {
            //alert("frequency is " + $(this).val());
            var frequency = $(this).val();

            if (frequency == 2) // 2 = Quarterly
            {
                document.getElementById("PayMonthFirst").val(1);
            }
        });    which clearly isn't right.

Comment: if you'd like to use it many dropdowns for the same aim, you can change "select[name=FrequencyId]" the selector to "select" or want to use just two of them you can use comma "select[name=FrequencyId], select[name=PayMonthOne]" you can get the same behaviour changing selector

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  I want to use the value from 'FrequencyId' to map to a value in another Html.DropDownFor menu i.e. if FrequencyId in DropDown 'a' = 2 then item in DropDown 'b' = 1.  So, in javascript I've written document.getElementById("b").val(1) to do this but it's not right.  What's the syntax for this in javascript?

Comment: Then, you don't need to change the first selector you can set the value of second dropdown just using val() inside of changing event of frequency select i.e if($(this).val() == "2") { $("#PayForMonth).val(1); }

Comment: I did it like this in the end:  <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).on("change", "select[name=FrequencyId]",
        function () {

            var frequency = $(this).val();

            if (frequency == 2) // 2 = Quarterly
            {
                document.getElementById('PayMonthOne').selectedIndex = 1;
                document.getElementById('PayMonthTwo').selectedIndex = 4;
                document.getElementById('PayMonthThree').selectedIndex = 7;
                document.getElementById('PayMonthFour').selectedIndex = 10;
            }


        });
</script>

Comment: you can use $("#PayMonthOne").val(1); instead of document.getElementById('PayMonthOne').selectedIndex = 1; and for others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the jQuery ready part like so:

```
function ddMonthChange () {
    var frequency = document.getElementById("FrequencyId")
        .options[document.getElementById("FrequencyId").selectedIndex].value;
    alert("frequency is " + frequency);
}
```

This is because `$(document).ready(...)` simply runs the function you pass in (in your case `ddMonthChange`) when the DOM has finished loading. Since you want your function to be available in the Global scope, so that the drop down can call it whenever it changes, you cannot pass it in to jQuery's ready function

If you want to read more about scope in Javascript: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/